# Approximation for sum of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have an exact CDF ($F_{X_i}(x)$) and PDF ($f_{X_i}(x)$) of a random variable $X_i\geq 0$ which includes special functions. Since I needed an approximation around $x=0$, I therefore derived an approximation  as 
$$F_{X_i}(x)\approx-a x \log(a x)$$ 
$$f_{X_i}(x)\approx-a (\log(a x)+1)$$
where $a>0$, and this CDF is a tight one.

However, now I need the CDF of 
$$Y=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i$$
where $X_i$s are i.i.d.

I tried to bound this by $\left( F_{X_i}(x)\right)^N$ or $\left( F_{X_i}(x/N)\right)^N$. I found that these are too loose even for small $N$.

If anyone has a good idea to derive $F_Y(y)$ more accurately at small $x$, please share with me.

Comment: CDF of sums of random variables usually complicate the problem. Have you tried other approaches, like characteristic functions or mgf? Do you really have to find a bound for the CDF of their sum? (Try to include the context in the question.)

Comment: take a look [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Central_limit_theorem)

Comment: I have a large $N$ approximation with the CLT, but looking for small or moderate number of $N$.